# Get frequency from dataset with repeated measurements over time

Tags: sas, statistics, frequency

this is my problem: I have a dataset that has 10 measurements over time, something like this:

```
ID  Expenditure  Age
25   100         89
25   102         89
25   178         89
25   290         89
25   200         89
.
.
.
26   100         79
26   102         79
26   178         79
26   290         79
26   200         79
.
.
.
27   100         80
27   102         80
27   178         80
27   290         80
27   200         80
.
.
.
```

Now I want to obtain the frequency of age, so I did this:

```
  proc freq data=Expenditure;
  table Age / out= Age_freq outexpect sparse;
  run;
```

Output:

```
 Age  Frequency Count  Percent of total frequency
 79   10         0.1
 80   140        1.4
 89   50         0.5
```

The problem is that this counts all rows, but doesn't take into account the repeated measurements per id. So I wanted to create a new colum with the actual frequencies like this:

```
data Age;
set Age_freq;
freq = Frequency Count /10;
run;
```

but I think sas doesn't recognize this 'Frequency Count' variable, can anybody gives me some insight on this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the duplicate records so that each ID had one record containing the age.

**Solution:** create a new table with the disticnt values of the ID and Age. then run the `proc freq`

**Code:**
I created a new table called Expenditure_ids that doesn't have any duplicate values for the ID & Age.

```
data Expenditure;
input ID  Expenditure  Age ;
datalines;
25   100         89
25   102         89
25   178         89
25   290         89
25   200         89
26   100         79
26   102         79
26   178         79
26   290         79
26   200         79
27   100         80
27   102         80
27   178         80
27   290         80
27   200         80
28   100         80
28   102         80
28   178         80
28   290         80
28   200         80
;
run;
proc sql;
create table Expenditure_ids as
select distinct ID, Age from Expenditure ;
quit;
proc freq data=Expenditure_ids;
  table Age / out= Age_freq outexpect sparse;
  run;
```

**Output:**

```
Age=79 COUNT=1 PERCENT=25 
Age=80 COUNT=2 PERCENT=50 
Age=89 COUNT=1 PERCENT=25
```